# changing auto increment value based on the last idinserted

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to change the auto increment value in MySQL via a query

```
ALTER TABLE log_visit AUTO_INCREMENT = (
    SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` + 500000
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'visit'
);
```

but this query is not working at all.

Please let me know what needs to be done in case we want to change auto increment based on the last inserted value.

Comment: Describe "not working at all". Are you getting an error? If so, what?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
    SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` + 500000
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    W' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the SQL error, it's due to the fact that the column isn't named "AUTO_INCREMENT" (and you also can't do a select inside an ALTER query). The reason is why is because AUTO_INCREMENT is not a column, but a MySQL attribute that, obviously, automatically increments.

If you'd like **AUTO_INCREMENT** to start at a certain value, in this case, 500000, you'd need to modify the table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` AUTO_INCREMENT=500000;
```

But it's recommended that if you're going to be changing the ID column at all, you should do so during table creation.

Comment: I even tried writing mysql procedure in order to acheive dynamic auto increment change, but still it's not working for me.

Comment: mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE RESETSEQ()
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE last_id INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
    -> DECLARE  sqlText text;
    -> SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` + 500000 into last_id FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'testtable';
    -> SELECT  last_id;
    -> SET @sql_text = 'ALTER TABLE testtable AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
    -> SET @temp_tb = last_id;
    -> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
    -> EXECUTE stmt USING @temp_tb;
    -> COMMIT;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: @Abhi It's possible to do what you're trying to do, and I'm not sure why you should need to. The ID column shouldn't really ever be modified. If you're going to do sorting or something, please make another INT column and make your changes there.

Comment: @Evans it seems that I have to create another column and perform operations up there

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

If you look at the docs it's clearly stated:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

this example sets the auto_increment to start at 100 from now on:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Comment: OP clearly wants to _add_ to the current auto_increment value, not just assign to some fixed value.

Comment: as i said this is just an example. surely the OP can extrapolate on the correct syntax to manipulate it to do what he wants such as finding the max current id and adding a value to it. the auto_increment start value is a static value so if OP wants to change all current values that is a different question

Comment: @PatrickQ You can't add to the auto_increment, you can set it's starting value however.

Comment: @EvanDarwin Yes, I'm aware of that. However, this "answer" doesn't really answer the question at all. If the OP knew how to "extrapolate on the correct syntax to manipulate it to do what he", then the question most likely wouldn't have been asked in the first place.

Comment: @PatrickQ So you're complaining about a user's attempt to answer a question that has no answer?

Comment: @EvanDarwin Instead of just basically saying "you can't do that", a good answer would say "you can't do it exactly that way, but here's how to accomplish what you ultimately want". Such an answer for this case would show how to fetch the current auto_increment value, add the desired amount to it, and then set auto_increment to the new value.